# Basic JavaScript how to call a function from the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started JavaScript basics and I'm struggling with this:
HTML page has the following:

```
<body>
    <p id="number">5</p>
    <button id="buttonX" onclick="calcSquare()">Click here!</button>
</body>
```

This page  should call the function `calcSquare()`, which fetches the value of the element, calculate its square, and print in the console: `The square of 5 is 25`. The HTML page loads the code, so I can refer to the page with the document keyword. My js code is following:

```
function calcSquare() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    console.log("The square of" + number + "is" number*number);
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with it? Thank you so much! Beginners struggles...

Comment: Missing a plus sign after `"is"`. Could use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead.

Comment: `.value` is only valid if you're using an `<input>`. Use `getElementById("number").textContent` instead.

Comment: If you want to work with `.value` you should consider using an `<input id="number" type="text">` instead. Then the user can dynamically change the value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your function itself.

Keep in mind that `.value` is used with an input element. So you can use `.innerHTML` or `.textContent`.

You forgot also the sign + after "is".

Look at this code snippet .

```js
function calcSquare() {
            var numbElementcontent = document.querySelector('#number').innerHTML;
            numbElementcontent = parseInt(numbElementcontent);
            console.log("The square of " + numbElementcontent + " is " + numbElementcontent * numbElementcontent);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="number">5</p>
    <button id="buttonX" onclick="calcSquare()">Click here!</button>

    <script>
        function calcSquare() {
            var numbElementcontent =     document.querySelector('#number').innerHTML;
            numbElementcontent = parseInt(numbElementcontent);
            console.log("The square of " + numbElementcontent + " is " + numbElementcontent * numbElementcontent);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `.value` use `.innerHTML`, and you are missing sign + after `"is"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get textContent,  and make some changes in your function `calcSquare()`

```js
function calcSquare() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var number = number.textContent;
    
    console.log("The square of" , number  , "is" , number*number);
    
   

}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="number">5</p>
    <button id="buttonX" onclick="calcSquare()">Click here!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you are use an input-field you make it more dynmaic :) and if the is target an input you can use the `.value`

Be sure you cast every time your vars into the right type before do math (`parseInt`, `parseFloat` etc)

And because you are new on JS please deal with JS Security - it is very important for your future dev..

https://snyk.io/learn/javascript-security/
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/disable-inline-javascript-for-security/

Answer (score -1):

Try this . Foe elements such as P or Div You have to ue textContent or innerHTML to get the data inside the tag. You missed string concatenation after  "is" too

```js
function calcSquare() {
var number = document.getElementById("number").textContent;

console.log("The square of" + number + "is" +number*number);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="number">6</p>
    <button id="buttonX" onclick="calcSquare()">Click here!</button>
</body>
<script>
```